# Are there any recent opinions on using PLINQO vs Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, plinqo

We are considering moving from Entity Framework to PLINQO L2S. EF has proven to be quite difficult for us to manage in an MVC3 application. I would agree there are areas of our application that can be improved, but overall, EF may not have been the best choice for us.

I am curious to know, recently, if anyone has moved form EF to PLINQO L2S? I have read many posts from back in 2010, but EF was a much different animal then. i am not interested in PLINQO for EF.

Comment: PLINQO. What a horrific name. I really hope they thought of it before PLINQ was made public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up evaluating PLINQO and found there were bugs trying to emulate our model generated by Entity Framework. It was not an issue with how EF generated the database, but rather an issue with [PLINQO appending numbers](http://community.codesmithtools.com/Template_Frameworks/f/66/p/12612/48824.aspx#48824) to collection entities. There was too much clean up for us to consider using PLINQO. It has some great features, but the generation caused us issues

We removed our DTO layer and decided to go with pure entities. The performance increase was huge. We tried several mapping libraries and even created our own direct mapping solution, but the cost in performance was too great.